# Convert Int column to Datetime in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a column generated as int from datasource, how can I change it to dispay minutes and seconds? Is there a property in Gridview?
For example. if I have value 70 to be shows as 01:10 or 1m 10s.
Edit: I did an event as suggested in comments :

```
   protected void Grid_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, ASPxGridViewColumnDataEventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (e.Column.FieldName == "AdsDisplayedSeconds" || e.Column.FieldName == "UndockedSeconds")
                    {
                        TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(e.Value.ToString()));
                        e.Value = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}",
                                            t.Minutes,
                                            t.Seconds);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LogHelper.LogError(ex);
                }
            }
```

When I am debugging, for record 70 for example, e.Value has value "01:10", but them in grid it is shown 70

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-6.0) instead [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-6.0).

Assumming your `int` always represents seconds:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(70);
Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString());
```

Comment: But in which event?

Comment: The first line of the above code only shows you how to convert your `int` value to `TimeSpam`, which it's what you want to draw on your `GridView`. You'll need to place it when you're drawing the grid. Your question doesn't show the written code for this purpose, so it's hard to know where it's needed to be placed.

Comment: hello, I added edit in my post, it is shown in e.Value the correct format, but then in grid it it still the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use converter to achive that

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(string))]
public class DateToNeededFormat : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object? value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return "";
        TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((int)value);
            
        return time.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\:fff", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
    }
 
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var strValue = value.ToString();
        
        return TimeSpan.TryParse(strValue, out TimeSpan result )? result.TotalSeconds : value;
    }
}
```

Than you need add resourse to Application.Resources

```
   <local:DateToNeededFormat x:Key="DateConverter"/>
```

After all you can use it next way

```
 <GridViewColumn 
        Header="Time" 
        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Time, Converter={StaticResource dateConverter}}"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a column in the GV with the int value?

Say, like this:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GHotels" runat="server" CssClass="table" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            width="45%" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowDataBound="GHotels_RowDataBound" AllowPaging="True"
            OnPageIndexChanging="GHotels_PageIndexChanging"   >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"    />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HotelName">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="txtHotel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' ></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-Width="270" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Seconds">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="txtSeconds" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Seconds") %>' ></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            
            
            </Columns>


            <PagerStyle CssClass="GridPager" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

code to load, say this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = 
                "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GHotels.DataSource = rstData;
                GHotels.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

And we now have this:

[image]

So, we have that column with seconds - we want to convert to HH:mm:ss

We can use the row data bound event, and add this code:

```
    protected void GHotels_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label txtSeconds = e.Row.FindControl("txtSeconds") as Label;
            TimeSpan MySeconds = new TimeSpan(0,0,Convert.ToInt32(txtSeconds.Text));

            txtSeconds.Text = MySeconds.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
        }
    }
```

And now we get:

[image]